# Extract Data from API and show in another page

Tags: reactjs, react-router

This question may sound silly to some people, but I am really confused on how to do it

I have 3 file: App.js, HomePage.js and Profile.js

App.js :

```
import React from "react"
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";  
import HomePage from "./components/HomePage";
import Profile from "./components/Profile"

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={HomePage} />
        <Route exact path="/profile/:profileId" component= {Profile} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}  
export default App;
```

From here, the default page it will go to is HomePage.js

HomePage.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

class HomePage extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            userData: [],
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get("XXXXXXXX").then((response) => {
            const userDataList = response.data.users;
            this.setState({
                userData: userDataList
            })
        })
    }
    render() {
        const userGrid = this.state.userData.map((user, index) => {
            return (
                <div key={index}>
                    <Link to={`/profile/${user.id}`}>
                        <img src={user.profilepicture} />
                        <p>{user.name}</p>
                    </Link>
                </div>
            )
        })
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <div className="card">
                    <div className="card__top">
                        <span className="card__title">
                            <p>Select An Account</p>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div className="card__bottom">
                        <div className="card__table">
                            {userGrid}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default HomePage;
```

In HomePage.js, I am able to show the profile picture and name of the user from API.
In the next page which is Profile.js , I am able to print the ID of the user.

Profile.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Profile extends Component{

    componentDidMount(){
        const uid = this.props.match.params.profileId;
    }
    render() {
        console.log(this.props.match);
        return(
        <h1>{this.props.match.params.profileId}</h1>
        )
    }
}
export default Profile;
```

As you can see I am printing the ID of user.
Here I also want to show the Profile Picture of the user which I selected in HomePage.js

This I am not able to do it.

JSON file:

```
{ - users: [-{id:1, name:"abc", profilepicture: "xxxxx.jpeg"}, ]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store a global state in your applicattion, which you can access from every connected component. This is a more complex topic. [redux](https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started) is a good framework to handle your global state changes.

Here is a tutorial: https://appdividend.com/2018/06/14/how-to-connect-react-and-redux-with-example/

I found it pretty hard to learn redux, but in the end it takes away a lot of pain. Because this is a problem you gonna have in every app you build with react.

Answer (score 0):

You need use [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) o [redux](https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started)

Example context API: https://ibaslogic.com/react-context-api/

Context's well to little projects, but Redux performs better.

Answer (score 0):

**App.js**

```
import React from "react"
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";  
import HomePage from "./components/HomePage";
import Profile from "./components/Profile"
import { UsersProvider } from "./UsersProvider.js";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <UsersProvider>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={HomePage} />
          <Route exact path="/profile/:profileId" component= {Profile} />
        </Switch>
      </UsersProvider>
    </Router>
  );
}  
export default App;
```

**UsersContext.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react"

const UsersContext = React.createContext();
const UsersProvider = UsersContext.Provider;
const UsersConsumer = TodosContext.Consumer;

class MyContext extends Component {
  state = {
   value: null,
  };

  setValue = (value) => {
    this.setState({ value });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <UsersProvider value={{ setValue, value }}>{this.props.children} 
      </UsersProvider>
    )
  }
}

export { UsersContext, UsersProvider, UsersConsumer }
```

---

**HomePage.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from 'axios';

class HomePage extends Component {
   
    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get("XXXXXXXX").then((response) => {
            const userDataList = response.data.users;
            // updating your context
            this.props.context.setValue(userDataList);
        })
    }

    render() {
       const userGrid = this.props.context.value.map((user, index) => {
        return (
            <div key={index}>
                <Link to={`/profile/${user.id}`}>
                    <img src={user.profilepicture} />
                    <p>{user.name}</p>
                </Link>
            </div>
        )
    })
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <div className="card">
                <div className="card__top">
                    <span className="card__title">
                        <p>Select An Account</p>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div className="card__bottom">
                    <div className="card__table">
                        {userGrid}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
}

export default HomePage;
```

---

**Profile.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { UsersConsumer } from "./UsersContext.js";

class Profile extends Component{

    render() {
        return(
          <UsersConsumer>
            {users => (
              <h1>{users.value.find(user => user.id === this.props.match.params.profileId)}</h1>
            )}
          </UsersConsumer>
        )
    }
}

export default Profile;
```

Comment: don't hesitate to ask questions. There are a lot of optimizations may be applied to the code above, but I think you don't need it for now.